# Why is JSONObject's getBoolean always returning false when using Android volley

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, android-volley

I am using android volley to perform some network request to a RESTful API. When I test the API locally using postman it returns the expected value of 'true'. It also returns the same value of 'true' when I use AsyncTask to fetch the boolean result from the JSON object returned. However, when I use volley to do the same operation the JSON response returned is always 'false' even when the value returned is actually true.

This is my code for the RESTful API.

```
 $app->post('/login', function () use ($app) {

// reading post params
$email = $app->request()->post('email');
$password = $app->request()->post('password');
$response = array();

//$db = new DbHandler ();
// check for correct email and password
if (true) {
    // get the user by email
    //$user = $db->getUserByEmail($email);



    $response ['error'] = true;
    $response ['message'] = 'Login failed. Incorrect credentials';



} else {
    // user credentials are wrong
    $response ["error"] = false;
    $response ['message'] = "Login Successful";
}

   echoRespnse(200, $response);
 });
```

And this is the value returned when I run it using postman

[image: the result returned in postman]

This is my volley operation

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button login;
private EditText email, password;
private boolean error;
private String message;

@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final RegisterInBackground registerGCMID = new RegisterInBackground();
            //registerGCMID.execute();

            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


            params.put("email", email.getText().toString());
            params.put("password", password.getText().toString());

            RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, ApplicationConstants.url_sign_in, new JSONObject
                    (params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        error = response.getBoolean(TAG_ERROR);
                        message = response.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error + " value of error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            requestQueue.add(request);


   if (!error) { //when it reaches here the error changes from true to false
   //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SportSelection.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
```

However it works when i do the EXACT same thing using AsyncTask

```
 class RegisterInBackground extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    JSONObject json;
    //boolean error;
    String message, userEmail, accountType;

 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


        Intent i;

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.getText().toString()));

        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(ApplicationConstants.url_sign_in, "POST", params);

        // check log cat for response
        //Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        try {
            error = json.getBoolean(TAG_ERROR);
            message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);


            if (!error) {


                i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                        SportSelection.class);
                startActivity(i);
                LoginActivity.this.finish();


                //Log.d("Message is", message);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

What is the value of error being changed to false after it has been assigned a value of true?

Comment: Have you logged the `JSONOBject response`?

Comment: yes I did i displayed it in a toss message and it said it was 'false'. I am wondering if it is an issue with volley

Comment: apparently getBoolean actually returned the correct value of 'true' however when i pass the value to the error variable it get charged to false. How can I fix that?

Comment: I realized that the getBoolean actually got the correct value of true however the value was changed to false before it reaches the if statement @SotiriosDelimanolis